# Firefox range slider move thumb above the track

Tags: css, firefox, range, mozilla

I have a custom styled range slider that works wonderfully on Chrome, however is not functioning on as intended on Firefox.

The main issue that I am facing is that on Chrome I am able to set the `margin-top` of the slider thumb to be a negative value which moves it up above the track as shown in the image below:
[image: desired design]

However, on Firefox I am unable to do this despite customizing the slider thumb. I am attaching a fiddle with my code:

```js
$( window ).on( "load", function() { 
    sliderValues();    
});

$( window ).resize(function() {
   sliderValues();  
});

let mouseDown;
$(document).mousedown(function() {
    mouseDown = true;
}).mouseup(function() {
    mouseDown = false;  
});


let stepChangeThreshold = 3000;


$('#range').on('mousemove',function(e){
    if (!mouseDown) return;
    
    this.previousClientX = this.previousClientX || e.clientX;
    let stepChangeThresholdPositionX = this.getBoundingClientRect().x+($('#range').width()*stepChangeThreshold/5500);
    
    
    if (this.value == stepChangeThreshold){
        if ((this.previousClientX > e.clientX) && (e.clientX < stepChangeThresholdPositionX)){
            this.step = 250;
        } else {
            this.step = 500;
        }
        
        
    }


    this.previousClientX = e.clientX;
});


$('#range').on('input', function() {    
  sliderValues();   

  var val = $('#range').val();  
  if (val >= stepChangeThreshold) {
      this.step = 500;
  } else {
      this.step = 250;
  };
  this.previousVal = val;
    
});

function sliderValues(){
    var val = $('#range').val();
    var min = $('#range').attr('min');
    var max = $('#range').attr('max');
    var portion = (val - min) / (max - min);
    $('#rangeV').html('<span>$'+ val +'</span>');
    $('#rangeV').css('left', portion * ($('#range').width() - 70));
    
    let thumbSliderRatio = (70/$('#range').width())*100;
    let fillPercent = Number(portion*(100-thumbSliderRatio) + thumbSliderRatio/2) + "%";
    
    $('#range').css('background','linear-gradient(to right, #008e39 0%, #008e39 ' + fillPercent + ', #ccc ' + fillPercent + ', #ccc 100%)');     
};
```

```css
.borrowheading {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 21px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 800;
    padding: 25px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

#range {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 20px 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #008e39 0%, #008e39 50%, #ccc 50%, #ccc 100%);
    border-radius: 8px;
    height: 7px;
    width: 100%;
    outline: none;
    
}
#range:focus {
    outline: none;
}

#range::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #008e39;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin-top: -100px;
}

#range::-moz-range-thumb {
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #008e39;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: -100px;
    border: none;
}

.range-wrap{
    width: 90%;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 120px;
}
.range-value{
    position: absolute;
}
.range-value span{
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 48px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-top: -64px;
}

.range-value span:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 36px;
    border: 2px solid #008e39;
    top: 55px;
    left: calc(50% - 1px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h4 class="borrowheading">How much would you like to borrow today?</h4>
<div class="range-wrap">
    <div class="range-value" id="rangeV"></div>
    <input id="range" type="range" min="500" max="5000" step="250" value="1000">
</div>
```

How can I raise my slider thumb by 100px on Firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the negative margin, you can use `transform`, and translate the range element towards the negative y axis. In addition, I gave the `span` containing the price a `z-index: 1` and decreased the height of the pseudo element which represents the connecting bar between the dragable range element and the slider itself.

```js
$( window ).on( "load", function() { 
    sliderValues();    
});

$( window ).resize(function() {
   sliderValues();  
});

let mouseDown;
$(document).mousedown(function() {
    mouseDown = true;
}).mouseup(function() {
    mouseDown = false;  
});


let stepChangeThreshold = 3000;


$('#range').on('mousemove',function(e){
    if (!mouseDown) return;
    
    this.previousClientX = this.previousClientX || e.clientX;
    let stepChangeThresholdPositionX = this.getBoundingClientRect().x+($('#range').width()*stepChangeThreshold/5500);
    
    
    if (this.value == stepChangeThreshold){
        if ((this.previousClientX > e.clientX) && (e.clientX < stepChangeThresholdPositionX)){
            this.step = 250;
        } else {
            this.step = 500;
        }
        
        
    }


    this.previousClientX = e.clientX;
});


$('#range').on('input', function() {    
  sliderValues();   

  var val = $('#range').val();  
  if (val >= stepChangeThreshold) {
      this.step = 500;
  } else {
      this.step = 250;
  };
  this.previousVal = val;
    
});

function sliderValues(){
    var val = $('#range').val();
    var min = $('#range').attr('min');
    var max = $('#range').attr('max');
    var portion = (val - min) / (max - min);
    $('#rangeV').html('<span>$'+ val +'</span>');
    $('#rangeV').css('left', portion * ($('#range').width() - 70));
    
    let thumbSliderRatio = (70/$('#range').width())*100;
    let fillPercent = Number(portion*(100-thumbSliderRatio) + thumbSliderRatio/2) + "%";
    
    $('#range').css('background','linear-gradient(to right, #008e39 0%, #008e39 ' + fillPercent + ', #ccc ' + fillPercent + ', #ccc 100%)');     
};
```

```css
.borrowheading {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 21px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 800;
    padding: 25px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

#range {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 20px 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #008e39 0%, #008e39 50%, #ccc 50%, #ccc 100%);
    border-radius: 8px;
    height: 7px;
    width: 100%;
    outline: none;
    
}
#range:focus {
    outline: none;
}

#range::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #008e39;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    transform: translateY(-65px);    
}

#range::-moz-range-thumb {
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #008e39;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    transform: translateY(-65px);  
}

.range-wrap{
    width: 90%;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 120px;
}
.range-value{
    position: absolute;
}
.range-value span{
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 48px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-top: -64px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.range-value span:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 32px;
    border: 2px solid #008e39;
    top: 55px;
    left: calc(50% - 1px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h4 class="borrowheading">How much would you like to borrow today?</h4>
<div class="range-wrap">
    <div class="range-value" id="rangeV"></div>
    <input id="range" type="range" min="500" max="5000" step="250" value="1000">
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Andy, thank you so much for this answer. I was thinking of using `position` and `top` but this also did not work. I can't  believe that it did not occur to me to use the `transform` style. Fantastic solution.

Comment: One thing that I will not incorporate from your answer however is the change to the connecting bar. While you are correct in fixing it on the fiddle, due to me incorporating web fonts, etc. on my website, the values that I had were in fact correct. Having said that, this is no fault of yours and I appreciate you taking the time to fix that also.